# Using Underscore.js To Merge/Combine and Sum Array Entries

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays of JSON objects which I'm looking to merge/combine together and then sum up the quantities of any matching entries.

Both of the arrays contain the same structure, one represents a list of equipment that is required to be used...

```
var required = [
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser855212" }, Type: undefined, Serialised: true, Quantity: 1 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser288945" }, Type: undefined, Serialised: true, Quantity: 1 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: undefined, Type: { ItemId: "itm71770" }, Serialised: false, Quantity: 5 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: undefined, Type: { ItemId: "itm11025" }, Serialised: false, Quantity: 2 }];
```

...and the other represents a list of equipment that actually has been used.

```
var used = [
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser663033" }, Type: undefined, Serialised: true, Quantity: 1 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser288945" }, Type: undefined, Serialised: true, Quantity: 1 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: undefined, Type: { ItemId: "itm71770" }, Serialised: false, Quantity: 2 }];
```

I have access to underscore.js and have been trying to use the _.groupBy and _.reduce methods to try and get the result I'm after but with no success. The result I'm looking to achieve is:

```
var result = [
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser663033" }, Type: undefined, Used: 1, Expected: 0, Remaining: 0 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser288945" }, Type: undefined, Used: 1, Expected: 1, Remaining: 0 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: { SerialNo: "ser855212" }, Type: undefined, Used: 0, Expected: 1, Remaining: 1 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: undefined, Type: { ItemId: "itm71770" }, Used: 2, Expected: 5, Remaining: 3 },
    { SerialisedEquipment: undefined, Type: { ItemId: "itm11025" }, Used: 0, Expected: 2, Remaining: 2 }];
```

I've also been looking at some of the Array methods that underscore provides but I'm not sure how I would use these to specify the criteria to merge by. Would anyone have any suggestions on the best way to achieve this?

*UPDATE*

I've managed to get the merged list of both of the arrays, removing duplicates...

```
// Split based on the serialised flag - so I know to look at either the serialNo or Type property
var isSerialised = _.groupBy(required, function (equip) {
    return equip.Serialised;
});

// Get all the required serialised equipment that is not already in the used list
var serialised = _.filter(isSerialised[true], function (value) {
    return (!_.some(used, function (equip) {
        return equip.SerialisedEquipment && equip.SerialisedEquipment.SerialNo == value.SerialisedEquipment.SerialNo;
    }));
});

// Get all the required types that are not already in the used list
var types = _.filter(isSerialised[false], function (value) {
    return (!_.some(used, function (equip) {
        return equip.Type && equip.Type.ItemId == value.Type.ItemId;
    }));
});

// Combine the equipment that is not in the list with the equipment that is in the list
var result = _.union(used, serialised, types);
```

I think it's now just a case now of looping through this results list with the required equipment list and summing up equipment that match based on serial number or type.

Comment: Hi qtheintro could you post your code to view your error!

Comment: Hi Papouche, I've been trying to get the result by using the underscore library and I'm not really getting an error but my code at the moment is getting nowhere near the right result, I'm more struggling on thinking through the problem and looking for perhaps a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime wanting to use a library to much makes you miss simpler algorithms:

```
var resultsById = {};
function getTemporaryId(value) {
    return value.SerialisedEquipment ? value.SerialisedEquipment.SerialNo : value.Type.ItemId;
}
function getResultForValue(value) {
    var id = getTemporaryId(value);
    if(!resultsById[id]) {
        resultsById[id] = {
            SerialisedEquipment: value.SerialisedEquipment,
            Type: value.Type,
            Used: 0,
            Expected: 0,
            Remaining: 0
        };
    }
    return resultsById[id];
}
_.each(required, function(value) {
    var result = getResultForValue(value);
    result.Expected += value.Quantity;
    result.Remaining += value.Quantity;
});
_.each(used, function(value) {
    var result = getResultForValue(value);
    result.Used += value.Quantity;
    result.Remaining = Math.max(result.Remaining - value.Quantity, 0);
});

var merged = _.values(resultsById);
```

---

If you really want to use lots of underscore, you can play with this solution:

```
var requiredValues = _.map(required, (function(value){
    //maybe want to clone value? value = _.clone(value);
    value.Used = 0;
    value.Expected = value.Quantity;
    return value;
}));
var usedValues = _.map(used, (function(value){
    //maybe want to clone value? value = _.clone(value);
    value.Used = value.Quantity;
    value.Expected = 0;
    return value;
}));
var mergedValues = _.chain(requiredValues.concat(usedValues))
    .groupBy(function(value){
        return value.SerialisedEquipment ? value.SerialisedEquipment.SerialNo : value.Type.ItemId;
    })
    .map(function(values) {
        var memo = {
            SerialisedEquipment: values[0].SerialisedEquipment,
            Type: values[0].Type,
            Used: 0,
            Expected: 0,
            Remaining: 0
        };
        return _.reduce(values, function(memo, value) {
            memo.Used += value.Used;
            memo.Expected += value.Expected;
            memo.Remaining = Math.max(memo.Expected - memo.Used, 0);
            return memo;
        }, memo)
    })
    .values()
    .value();
```

Comment: I struggled to get close to one solution and you came up with two!, I really appreciate your time and help, there is some additional requirements but I'll be able to make adjustments to you solution. Thanks again, I'll mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Array.concat() method:

```
var result = required.concat(used);
```

and it will make merge for you.

EDIT

Though if you want to use undescore method _.union(arr1,arr2) is for you!

Comment: Thanks Arsenii, that merges the arrays together but do you know if there is a way to sum up the entries that are going to be merged by the concat/union?

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understand what do you mean by "sum up the entries". As I can see, you have seven different objects each of which has only one entrie..

Comment: I got it. I will think about the solutions and write you if I have any. BR

Comment: Hi Arsenii, thank for the help. As you've already spotted I'm looking to some up the equipment Used, Expected and Remaining from both lists too. I've managed to merge the lists together - ugly code I know - and updated the question, so I'm now just working on how to get the quantities summing up.